# Second part of my javascript isn't executing after rendering some JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Hey guys I was wondering why my last script in this file isn't working - its suppose to take the value that is being pulled from JSON and compare it to a set value. Thanks for all the help everyone!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/tenniswarehouse?callback=?";


$.getJSON(url,function(json){
    var html = "<div id=\"tester\">" + json.likes + "</div>";
    //A little animation once fetched
     $('.facebookfeed').html(html);

 });
 });
 </script>
 </head>
  <body onload="timeMsg()">
   <div class="facebookfeed">
    <h2></h2>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var x =document.getElementById("tester").innerHTML;
  if (x < 56700) {
  document.write("worked")
  }
 else {
 document.write("didn't work")
 }
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this to be in a function, like:

```
function myFunc() {
  var x =document.getElementById("tester").innerHTML;
  if (x < 56700) {
     document.write("worked")
  }
  else {
     document.write("didn't work")
  }
}
```

And then call it like so:

```
$.getJSON(url,function(json){
    var html = "<div id=\"tester\">" + json.likes + "</div>";
    //A little animation once fetched
     $('.facebookfeed').html(html);

     myFunc();
   });
```

Because you are executing that code before tester is added to the DOM.

Comment: try<  document.write(x) and see what that value is

Comment: I did and it doesn't come up with anything - is it working for you?

Answer (score 1):

Your function in head is executed on page load. However, javascript code in body is executed when the page is rendered (before page load), therefore it is **executed prior to AJAX request**.

To fix that, you should move the script from body to json handler. like that:

```
$(function() {

    var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/tenniswarehouse?callback=?";

    $.getJSON(url,function(json){
        var html = "<div id=\"tester\">" + json.likes + "</div>";
        //A little animation once fetched
        $('.facebookfeed').html(html);
        var x =document.getElementById("tester").innerHTML;
        if (x < 56700) {
            document.write("worked")
        } else {
            document.write("didn't work")
        }    
    });
});
```

Comment: strange that didn't work for - I put that body - should I put it somewhere else?